# Handling incoming socket data

Tags: c#, .net, socket

Below I have some code that I use to handle incoming socket data, this is not full thing but its the part I am worried about, is there any way to improve this?

```
int packetPosition = 0;
                while (packetPosition < packetData.Length)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int MessageLength = Apple.Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++] });
                        uint MessageId = Apple.Encoding.DecodeUInt32(new byte[] { packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++] });

                        byte[] Content = new byte[MessageLength - 2];

                        for (int i = 0; i < Content.Length && packetPosition < packetData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Content[i] = packetData[packetPosition++];
                        }

                        IncomingPacket incomingPacket = new IncomingPacket(MessageId, Content);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _log.Error(e);
                        Apple.Game.PlayerManager.DisposePlayer(_playerData.PlayerId);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It'd be appreciated to have the `full thing`. It'd make this much easier to understand and therefore help you! :)

Comment: Is that your original indentation?

Comment: Naming variables with capital letter is really confusing, and at odds with C# convention (`int MessageLength`, `uint MessageId`, `byte[] Content`), especially since you're not even consistent about it (`int packetPosition`, `IncomingPacket incomingPacket`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the completely broken indentation is a paste glitch (right?), this bit hits me first:

> ```
> catch (Exception e)
> {
>     _log.Error(e);
>     Apple.Game.PlayerManager.DisposePlayer(_playerData.PlayerId);
> }
> ```

If `DisposePlayer` does what it *seems* to be doing, then this looks like dangerous code that's begging for `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown at another, unrelated point in time.

And if your logging framework ever gets configured to throw exceptions, and `_log.Error(e);` actually throws (IDK, error writing to log file for example), then `DisposePlayer` is never going to get called.

That's why disposal of resources should happen in a `finally` block.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.Error(e);
    disposePlayer = true;
}
finally
{
    if (disposePlayer)
    {
        Apple.Game.PlayerManager.DisposePlayer(_playerData.PlayerId);
    }
}
```

That way you know that that bit of code will run *no matter what*. I added a little `bool disposePlayer` local variable here, because a `finally` block will run *whether an exception is caught or not*, and you only need to call that method when an exception is effectively thrown.

I'm just not comfortable seeing an object being disposed by someone else than its creator, but you haven't given us enough code to chew on for me to expand on this point.

---

I think these two lines take up too much horizontal space:

> ```
> int MessageLength = Apple.Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++] });
> uint MessageId = Apple.Encoding.DecodeUInt32(new byte[] { packetData[packetPosition++], packetData[packetPosition++] });
> ```

I would be better to give it vertical height, so that the reader can more easily see how many times `packetPosition` is being incremented in the process:

```
int MessageLength = Apple.Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] 
{ 
    packetData[packetPosition++], 
    packetData[packetPosition++], 
    packetData[packetPosition++] 
});
uint MessageId = Apple.Encoding.DecodeUInt32(new byte[] 
{ 
    packetData[packetPosition++], 
    packetData[packetPosition++] 
});
```